# Windows BATCH script error - do ( was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I try to run a simple batch script as shown below. Basically I want to visit each sub-directory in a given directory and run a gmake command.

```
echo %USER_DEF_VAR%
cd %USER_DEF_VAR%\topLevelDir
for /D %G in ("%USER_DEF_VAR%\topLevelDir\*") do ( 
cd %G
gmake clean
gmake 
)
```

If I run this script on a command line, it works fine. But when I put this in a .bat script it throws me an error saying

> do ( was unexpected at this time.

I have tried removing spaces wherever possible  as suggested here - [nested For loop in batch file error: Do was unexpected at this time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949579/nested-for-loop-in-batch-file-error-do-was-unexpected-at-this-time)

I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: I had a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134137/windows-command-works-from-command-prompt-but-not-in-cmd-file-any-idea-why) and it turned out that I needed two percents in the batch file. Try that.

Comment: Yep worked for me too :) , Thanks Endoro & Mr Moose :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a batch script you have to double the `%`:

```
for /D %%G in ("%USER_DEF_VAR%\topLevelDir\*") do ( 
cd "%%~G"
...
)
```